# How to get the List of products name whose name starts with numbers using LINQ query.?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a table from where i want to retrieve the list of products whose name starts with 0 to 9.
Code snippet.

`List<string> searchItems = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };`

`.....Where(x=> searchItems.Any(y=> y.StartsWith(x.ProductName))).ToList();`

I am not getting the list of products, getting 0 records, Anyone plz suggest me a better and correct query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `x.ProductName.StartsWith(y)` rather than `y.StartsWith(x.ProductName)`.

The way you're doing it now you're asking `"1".StartsWith("Your Product name")`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use proper identifiers. This will help you to find your error:

```
var result = products.Where(product => searchItems.Any(
    searchItem => searchItem.StartsWith(product.ProductName)))
```

So you keep only those Products that have a ProductName, where there is at least one search item that starts with this name.

- Your search items:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- ProductName = 19987.

Is there any search item that starts with product name 19987?

> I have a table from where i want to retrieve the list of products whose name starts with 0 to 9.

If you rephrase this the query will be simple:

> I want to query all products that have a ProductName that starts with a digit

```
var productsWithDigitStartName = dbContext.Products
    .Where(product => Char.IsDigit(product.ProductName[0]));
```

Comment: `searchItems` is a list of single character strings. It's unlikely that `product.ProductName` is a single character string so `searchItem.StartsWith(product.ProductName)` is almost always likely to be `false`. Now `product.ProductName.StartsWith(searchItem)` is far more likely to be what the OP wants.